# ASP.NET MVC Software Design Pattern: DI,Repository,Service Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**EDIT**

Should i put service layer and repository layer into one project, so the web project is able to reference to DbContext objects ? Now my web(controllers) are unable to reference to dbcontext objects. what is the right way?

```
// service and repository are together
(View <- Controller) -> (Service -> Repository -> EF DbContext) -> (DB) 
// separate service and repository layer
(View <- Controller) -> (Service) -> (Repository -> EF DbContext) -> (DB)
```

**Below are original question**

i know SO is an excellent community to post my questions about mvc design patterns. Please give me your advice and I will appreciate your help. Thank you!

We are planning for a new project and our priority is to develop an application that is extensible and loosely-coupled.

I am new to software development; I did some reading on [MVC Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1), and followed by a book called [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework by Steven Sanderson (Apress)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040),From the book, I learnt about DDD(Domain driven design) and some other concepts like repository and dependency injection. I have followed the book to build the SportsStore website, and gained some basic understanding about DI. But I personally think that the example did not separate the business logic layer, so i did a research on that, i found a pattern called Service Layer Pattern, and from what i understand, it separates the Business logic layer. Based on this, I came out with a structure for my new project(sample project below).

Do i need to implement **IDisposable** interface? if yes, where and why?
Is this structure feasible for a relatively big-scale project?

sample database design: **Product(one)----(many)ProductCategoryRs(many)----(one)Category**

the solution contains 3 projects: Repository,Service,Web

**Repository:**

**Define IRepository interface , basic CRUD operations**

**Are these signatures sufficient? Should I add *TEntity GetById(object id);*?**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> All { get; }
    void Create(TEntity item);
    void Update(TEntity item);
    void Delete(TEntity item);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

**Implement generic Repository class**

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    STOREEntities context;
    public Repository()
    {
        context = new STOREEntities();
    }
    public IQueryable<TEntity> All
    {
        get
        {
            return context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    }
    public void Create(TEntity item)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Add(item);
    }
    public void Update(TEntity item)
    {
        context.Entry<TEntity>(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }
    public void Delete(TEntity item)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(item);
    }
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Service:
Define IProductService interface, extend business logic here.**

```
public interface IProductService
{
    IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; }
    IEnumerable<Product> Get(Expression<Func<Product, Boolean>> filter);
    Product GetByProductId(int productId);
    void AddProduct(Product product);
    void EditProduct(Product product);
    void RemoveProduct(Product product);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

**Implement Product Service**

```
    public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    IRepository<Product> repository; //Inject
    public ProductService(IRepository<Product> repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products
    {
        get { return repository.All; }
    }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter)
    {
        return repository.All.Where(filter);
    }
    public Product GetByProductId(int productId)
    {
        return repository.All.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
    }
    public void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        repository.Create(product);
    }
    public void EditProduct(Product product)
    {
        repository.Update(product);
    }
    public void RemoveProduct(Product product)
    {
        repository.Delete(product);
    }
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        repository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Web project, retrieve data from service and convert to viewmodel and display.
ProductController code**

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    IProductService productService; //inject
    public ProductController(IProductService service)
    {
        productService = service;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = productService.Products; //retrieve from service layer
        return View(products);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you **really should** add a `TEntity GetById(int id)` to your `IRepository<TEntity>` generic interface.

Why? Because if you don't, and if you want to fetch a single record on your business layer, you only have two options (on the repository, data-access layer):

1. Return a complete, "unlazy" collection, meaning that you'll return, say, 100,000 records in order to use a single one.
2. Return a lazy collection like `IQueryable<TEntity>`, which, yes, will allow you to get a single record from the database, but may cause a lot of [nasty side-effects](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc/).

The first option is clearly wrong. The second is controversial, but (unless your project has you as a single developer, and you really really really know what you're doing) it is potentially leaky and unsafe. So, if you do need a single record (and sometimes you'll surely do), expose a method that does exactly that.

Having said that, you should also **not** expose `IQueryable<TEntity> All { get; }`, for exactly the same reasons above. Use `IEnumerable<TEntity> All { get; }` instead, and make your concrete generic repository class return a real collection, by calling `context.Set<TEntity>().ToList()` for instance.

**Edit**

Regarding IDisposable:

There are only two (related) reasons for implementing the IDisposable interface that I can think of:

1. Disposing unmanaged resources
2. A cool way of [implementing the RAII pattern](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/RAII-and-IDisposable-and-Thoughts-About-OO.aspx).

In your case, you probably *should* use it on your repository implementation. Please take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975760/should-linq-to-sql-repository-implement-idisposable) for further information.

Comment: -1, Although you have good insight into GetById, it wasn't the answer to any of the OP's questions.

Comment: @Levitikon: he asked about `IDisposable` and I answered it. That's 1 answer (at least that's how I learned to count, not sure about you :P)